# Find solutions to a Diophantine Eq.

Tags: number-theory

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Methods for quartic diophantine equation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/134987/methods-for-quartic-diophantine-equation)

Find all solutions of the Diophantine Equation
3x^2 + 2y^4 = z^4

I have just found x=0, y=o, and z=0.
I think that I need to use some congruence theory here, but I'm not really sure. I was suggested that if I tried the assumption that either y or z are divisible by three I would get a contradiction, but I have worked on it, and I can't really see it.

Comment: I just asked about [this exact same equation](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/134987/methods-for-quartic-diophantine-equation)... where did you come across it?

Comment: It's homework. I read your question, and that's exactly what I need to know: how do you decide to use congruence mod3? I already have a solution,but I just don't understand it.

Comment: Well there *is* a $3$ in the equation, but I feel your pain. I tried to get a motivation for that selection of modulus, to no avail...

Comment: Sorry, Nathan, you're not making sense. In the question you say you don't have a solution, in the comment you say you do. Why don't you rethink your question, lay all your cards on the table, and ask us what you really want to ask.

Comment: @TheChaz, I give what amounts to a procedure at your related question, with a link to a key ingredient at another of my answers.

Comment: @WillJagy: I saw that, and have symbolically indicated my gratitude with an upvote. I'll have to think about it after some sleep. Thanks (again?)!